# Can't figure out how to make xp bar

Tags: discord.js

```
const bar_fill_start = "<:filledinstart:966733512428384296>"
const bar_fill_end = "<:filledinend:966733512088649759>"
const bar_fill_middle = "<:filledinmiddle:966733512449355796>"

const bar_empty_start = "<:emptystart:966733512457728000>"
const bar_empty_end = "<:emptyend:966733512499691700>"
const bar_empty_middle = "<:emptymiddle:966733512390615041>"

function generateXpBar(xp, level) {
    let bar = bar_fill_start + "";
    let barLength = 6;
    let xpToNextLevel = Levels.xpFor(level);
    let xpToNextLevelPercent = xp / xpToNextLevel;
    console.log(xpToNextLevelPercent);
    for (let i = 0; i < barLength; i++) {
        if (i < Math.floor(barLength * xpToNextLevelPercent) - 1) {
            bar += bar_fill_middle;
        } else {
            if(i <= Math.floor(barLength * xpToNextLevelPercent) - 1) {
                bar += bar_empty_middle;
            }else {
                bar += bar_empty_end;
            }
        }
    }


    return bar;
}
```

[image: xp]
[image]

On audite it looks good. But on kitten it doesn't
what am i doing wrong ?
Can't figure out where is the error I make since it looks good on audite but not on kitten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(i <= Math.floor(barLength * xpToNextLevelPercent) - 1) {
```

to

```
if(i < barLength - 1) {
```

after first else